# How to display checkout session value in ZIP/Postal code textbox in checkout page - Magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

How we can display checkout session postcode value in **Zip/postcode** text-box under "**Estimate Shipping and Tax**" in cart page.

Please help me to find solution for this issue.